# Web crawler: want to ignore login windows

Tags: web-access, webservices

I'm trying to make web crawler with Mathematica.

```
 webcrawler[rooturl_, depth_] := 
   Flatten[
     Rest[
       NestList[
         Union[Flatten[
           Thread[# -> Import[#, "Hyperlinks", "ServerAuthentication" -> False ]] & 
            /@ Last /@ #]] &, 
         {"" -> rooturl}, depth]]];
```

It's working well. The only problem is that whenever there is a link with user and password authentication, a box is poping up and I need to click Cancel. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: `URLFetch` has an option `"DisplayProxyDialog" -> False` but I don't know if that's what you are after since a working example is missing.

Comment: Do you mind posting more of the code that you have used?